# How can I show the data of two opposite tables?

Tags: sql, join, outer-join

I have the following tables with some information inserted in them. Here is an example:

**Table Person**

```
id_person       name
--------------------------
   1            name1
   2            name2
   3            name3
   4            name4
   5            name5
   6            name6
```

**Table Professor**

```
id_professor (references id_person)
------------
     1
     2
     5
     6
```

**Table Student**

```
id_student (references id_person)
----------
    1
    3
    4
    5
```

I want to execute a `select` that shows almost all the data from all the tables but with only from those persons that are wether a student OR a professor. So the output I want to get, given this example is:

```
 name        id_professor      id_student      
-------------------------------------------
 name2           2                NULL
 name3          NULL               3
 name4          NULL               4
 name6           6                NULL
```

How can I do this?

I have tried doing this query without any success:

```
select p.name, s.id_student, pr.id_professor from 
person p inner join student s on p.id_person = s.id_student right join professor r on s.id_student = pr.id_professor
where (s.id_student is null) or (pr.id_professor is null);
```

Comment: You are missing one join, `person` to `professor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two `left join`s and some filtering:

```
select p.name, pr.id_professor, s.id_student
from person p left join
     professor pr
     on pr.id_professor = p.id_person left join
     student s
     on s.id_student = p.id_person
where (pr.id_professor is not null and s.id_student is null) or
      (pr.id_professor is null and s.id_student is not null);
```

Comment: Does the order of the elements in the `on` matter? Would `pr.id_professor = p.id_person` work as fine as `p.id_person = pr.id_professor`?

Comment: @user157629 . . . Those express the same condition between the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you all the persons who are either person or professor or both

```
select p.name, pr.id_professor, s.id_student
from person p 
left join professor pr on pr.id_professor = p.id_person 
left join student s on s.id_student = p.id_person
where s.id_student is not null or pr.id_professor is not null
```